# How to wrap XSLT code without breaking lines in the output

Tags: xslt

I'm using Eclipse IDE to write XSLT code to extract data from XML's to a CSV with a Header line. The issue I have is, if I give a line break in the code to fit the code in to the IDE window the output gives the same line break - I need to have it in a single line in the output (it's a comma delimited CSV).

Example:

```
Expected Output: A,B,C,D,E

1:<p>
Header line in XSLT:<p>
   A,B,C,D,E <p>
Output:<p>
   A,B,C,D,E
<p>
2:<p>
Header line in XSLT:<p>
   A,B,<p>
   C,D<p>
Output:<p>
   A,B,<p>
   C,D
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to enclose the text in [`xsl:text`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Text) elements. This should work because adjacent text nodes are automatically merged:

```
<xsl:text>A,B,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>C,D</xsl:text>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works fine for text, but what if the line has code i.e. <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="main/updated = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'"><xml:element name="publisheddate"><xsl:value-of select="main/modified">
</xsl:value-of></xml:element></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise><xsl:element name="publisheddate"><xsl:value-of select="main/updated"/></xsl:element></xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>

Comment: Your question implies that this is for text only, because of the commas.
But as long as you enclose any plain text in `<xsl:text>` elements,
that should still work, even if elements are in-between.